# Design a tableView with custom cells

Tags: ios, swift

I created a table view with different custom cell. I have a `userTableView` class which contain the table view and I also created different classes, such as `ageDataPickerVtableViewCell`, each one associated with a `xib` file and represent a cell in the table. I am not sure how to design the app to be able to get the input from the whole cells and regroup them into one class to be able to send the request to the server. For example when a date is selected on the `dataPicker`, with the actual design I can access the date only on the `ageDataPickerVtableViewCell`. Shall I create an outlet of every element on the `userTableView` class to be able to access all the selected values on one class?

Comment: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/ go through some tutorials about UITableView. Here I've mentioned one is also good tutorial

Comment: It dose not help. I created multiple tables and have no problem with that. Ny problem is how to share information between different custom cells. Imagin a cell containing a UIPickerView and another custom cell containing a UILabel. I want to change the label value when the UIPicker value change. I could set the UIlabel class es delegate for the UIPicker but I am not sure that it's a good idea...

Comment: You should update your question in a more proper way then. `Design a tableView with custom cells` this title leads to the link I've shared

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a closure. Pass that closure to your cell and when it performs an action call this closure.

For example in you `geDataPickerVtableViewCell` create a variable `var onDataSelect: (Any) -> ()`. In the `func pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)` you should call this closure. (I suppose that you are using a `UIPickerView`)

**EDIT**

```
class ageDataPickerVtableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var onDataSelect: ((Any) -> ())!

    // Your code (you have to assign self to picker's delegate in this class)

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
         let optionSelected = // Retrieve your selection
         onDataSelect(optionSelected)
    }
}
```

And in the `UITableViewController` or in `UITableViewControllerDataSource`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: dataPickerIdentifier)
      if let cell = cell as? ageDataPickerVtableViewCell {
          cell.onDataSelect = { data in 
              // Save that data (you can use indexPath to know which field of the form belongs)
          }
      }

      return cell;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean